# No longer able to compile LuaLaTeX after MikTeX update

Tags: luatex, miktex, compilation-error, update

I just updated `MikTeX` from the console. Even with the following MWE (I guess MNWE in this case)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    I hate it here
\end{document}
```

I get the errors

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\test.tex:1: Extra \endcsname. []
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\test.tex:1: Missing { inserted. []
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\test.tex:1: Missing control sequence inserted. []
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\test.tex:1: Extra \endcsname. []
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\test.tex:1: Missing { inserted. []
```

which is pretty annoying to be honest. In short, I cannot compile *anything* with **Lua** after the update, everything shows me precisely these errors.

A more complete log of the MNWE above reads as follows:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.6.29) (format=lualatex 2022.4.2)  2 APR 2022 13:32
 restricted system commands enabled.
**C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/test.tex
(C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-03-18 3.21 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-02-24.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fo
ntloader-2022-02-24.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.119
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'
.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
! Extra \endcsname.
\exp_args:Nc ...>\exp_after:wN #1\cs:w #2\cs_end: 
                                                  
l.1 
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
\exp_after:wN 
l.1 
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
\inaccessible 
l.1 
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

! Extra \endcsname.
\exp_args:Nc ...>\exp_after:wN #1\cs:w #2\cs_end: 
                                                  
l.1 
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
\exp_after:wN 
l.1 
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching rig
```

I don't know what is meant by "a left brace was mandatory here" or that kind of stuff.

Comment: Your versions looks out of sync. Check for updates in user and admin mode in the MiKTeX console.

Comment: your binary is a lot older than mine on a current miktex, you have `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)` and I have `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (MiKTeX 22.3)`.

Comment: I actually ended up reinstalling MikTeX, but it's fixed now. I also have the version you mention now. Thanks a lot!